# How does an undefined system call return -1?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have defined a 'helloworld' system call in my Linux kernel and recompiled it. The code for the system call is:

```
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/sched.h>
#include<linux/syscalls.h>
#include "processInfo.h"
asmlinkage long sys_listProcessInfo(void)
{
    printk("Hello World. My new syscall..FOSS Lab!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But when I'm calling this system call from the same operating system with another kernel version, which does not include this system call, using the below code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<sys/syscall.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
    long int var = syscall(326);
    printf("Returning: %ld\n",var);
    return 0;
}
```

The variable `var` gets the value -1. I would like to know how `var` gets -1 instead of displaying an error.

Comment: I would guess that the source code for `syscall` is setup to return a -1 if an unregistered vector is requested.

Comment: Here is an article that explains how the internals of a system call work:  http://lwn.net/Articles/604287 .  I don't have time to read it all now, but the answer can probably be found in there, or at least enough information to get you pointed in the right direction.  But to echo @MichaelDorgan's comment, syscall() probably just returns -1 if the requested system call doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you expect an error? The `syscall` function exists, the linker can resolve it. So there won't be an error from the compiler or linker.
When you run the executable, the old kernel's `syscall` function detects that  326 is an invalid system call number and the functions returns -1, probably with `errno` set to `ENOSYS` = system call not implemented.